# How to configure xampp on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-server-2012-r2

I've configured xampp on my server but when I try to access it remotely via browser it doesn't work. Localhost works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Apache enabled, and listening on port 80.

Comment: But he is enabled already. Localhost is working fine but when I try to access via browser is not working.

Example
192.168.0.0 via browser in my machine not working, but
localhost or 127.0.0.1 on local server is working.